# Access object created in another function

Tags: perl

My program creates an object, which, in turn, creates another object

#### MainScript.pm

```
use module::FirstModule qw ($hFirstModule);

$hFirstModule->new(parametres);
$hFirstModule->function();
```

#### FirstModule.pm

```
use Exporter   ();
@EXPORT = qw($hFirstModule);
use module::SecondModule qw ($hSecondModule);

sub new {
    my $className = shift;
    my $self = { key => 'val' };
    bless $self, $classname;

    return $self;
}

sub function{
    $hSecondModule->new(parametres);
    #some other code here
}
```

I want to acces `$hSecondModule` from `MainScript.pm`.

Comment: Return the object based on conditional and assign to a variable?

Comment: Please show the actual code you are using, or at least a [mcve]. Without that it's not possible to conclusively answer your question. If you [edit] the question and include what you're actually doing I will update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I updated my code

Comment: In the function, the second object is not returned, does that mean that it's lexically scoped and I can't acces it by any way? I cannot modify FirstModule, this is why I'm trying to do that

Comment: `function()` is supposed to return the last true value it evaluated, so it's supposed to be the second module object. Can't you just `my $obj2 = $hFirstModule->function()`?

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but after that object creation there is more code

Comment: In that case, if you can't modify FirstModule, I don't know of any way to access that object since it is, apparently, dying at the end of `function`

Comment: You need to @highlight if you want to answer to a comment so it gives a notification. Only the author of a post gets notified automatically of new comments. That said, why does it create a `$hSecondModule` object anyway? And why is there a classname in a class variable that gets exported? That's weird. Anyway, so the `#some other code here` is a bunch of more statements? And the final return is something else? You could do a bit of ugly hacking... I'll add another answer.

Comment: @simbabque The code is more complex, I added only the parts which involves my question. The $hSecondModule object is more complex and it is used in a other modules, I don't know why the ones that wrote this decided to use this architecture. `#some other code here` involves more statements which alter the final return

Comment: See my other answer for some inspiration.

Comment: Is `SecondModule` really object-oriented, or is it a function library (uses `Exporter`)? You have `FirstModule` doing both, which is possible but very undesirable.

Comment: @Borodin it is object oriented. `MainScript` starts the execution and the subroutine `function` basically includes all of the other modules, inside that subroutine all the objects are created ( or subroutinesfrom other modules are called, and those subroutines create other objects and so on). I wanted that after the execution of all the stuff to acces one of the objects to extract some final data.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still puzzled about your structure. Conventionally a `.pm` file is a *Perl module* while `.pl` is used for a program file. It is also vital to use capital letters for class names, so `module::FirstModule` should be `Module::FirstModule`, and the code should be in file `Module/Firstmodule.pm` while the calling code must `use Module::FirstModule`. If you are using an object-oriented approach then you must drop all use of `Exporter`. Beyond that it sounds like you just need to create a `Module::SecondModule` as a part of the `Module::FirstModule` object, which is trivial.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, that is the structure. The code is already written (not by me) and it is object-oriented-ish, removing the `use Exporter` will break it so I won't really mess with that. I don't want to modify the `FirstModule` or `SecondModule`. My hope was that all the created objects deep in the code flow are available from the `MainScript` after the execution of subroutine `function`

Comment: But of course, that would destroy the purpose of scoping so I guess I'm stuck with that.

Comment: Does it actually export variables and those contain class names? That's just plain weird. Why does it do that?

Comment: @simbabque Yes, this is what it does. `$hFirstModule` would be the class name of `module::FirstModule` and when I create an object, I create it with `$hFirstModule->new( 'parameters')`. I ask myself the same thing every day :D

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. But well, if you know that it's weird and not the usual way to do stuff, then it's a good experience. Working with code like that teaches you a lot. I think it's invaluable. You learn to pay attention to details, be aware of what you do, and dealing with extra-strange stuff. And of course you learn how not to do things and in the future you will be able to argue very effectively why doing it like this is a bad idea. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very hacky approach that takes your updated code into consideration. It uses [Sub::Override](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Override) to grab the return value of the constructor call to your SecondModule thingy. This is something that you'd usually maybe do in a unit test, but not in production code. However, it should work. Here's an example.

*Foo.pm*

```
package Foo;
use Bar;

sub new {
    return bless {}, $_[0];
}

sub frobnicate {
    Bar->new;
    return;
}
```

*Bar.pm*

```
package Bar;

sub new {
    return bless {}, $_[0];
}

sub drink {
    return 42;    # because.
}
```

*script.pl*

```
package main;
use Foo; # this will load Bar at compile time
use Sub::Override;

my $foo = Foo->new;

my $bar;          # this is lexical to the main script, so we can use it inside
my $orig = \&Bar::new;           # grab the original function
my $sub  = Sub::Override->new(
    "Bar::new" => sub {
        my $self = shift;

        # call the constructor of $hSecondModule, grab the RV and assign
        # it to our var from the main script
        $bar = $self->$orig(@_);
        return $bar;
    }
);

$foo->frobnicate;

# restore the original sub
$sub->restore;

# $bar is now assigend
print $bar->drink;
```

Again, I would not do this in production code.

Let's take a look at the `main` function. It first creates a new Foo object. Then it grabs a reference to the `Bar::new` function. We need that as the original, so we can call it to create the object. Then we use Sub::Override to temporarily replace the `Bar::new` with our sub that calls the original, but takes the return value (which is the object) and assigns it to our variable that's lexical to the main script. Then we return it.

This function will now be called when `$foo->frobnicate` calls `Bar->new`. After that call, `$bar` is populated in our main script. Then we restore `Bar::new` so we don't accidentally overwrite our `$bar` in case that gets called again from somewhere else.

Afterwards, we can use `$bar`.

Note that this is advanced. I'll say again that I would not use this kind of hack in production code. There is probably a better way to do what you want. There might be an x/y problem here and you need to better explain why you need to do this so we can find a less crazy solution.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt, and I think would make it clearer, if you were to separate your module files and your main source

Comment: @borodin yes, I will do that later. I was aiming for easy copying. I always hate having to create several files when I try code. So I try to make it convenient for people.

Comment: I agree that it makes your code easier to test, but it will be much harder, especially for the more naive readers, to convert what you have written into separate module files. I think the guys who want to contract your code into a single source file are likely to be less handicapped and less frequent than those who need to expand a monoblock into individual sources. It may also bypass people thst the "proper" way is to use multiple library files unless you say so explicitly. Thanks for a great answer.

Comment: @Borodin I just changed it. I agree with you fully.

Comment: So I see! Thanks for all you do here.

Comment: @Borodin I'll hand that compliment right back to you. :)

Comment: @simbabque even though it's not that safe to do this, I really like this hack!

Comment: Hmm thank you, but many of my contributions are marred by my anger issues. It is always my intention to appear to be friendly, but sometimes it doesn't happen. Occasionally there are jerks whom I think deserve the blunt end of my pen, but that doesn't happen often. Please bear with me -- I am working on my inadequacies.

Comment: @Borodin I don't think it's that bad. I think a lot of people actually function like that. It kind of conforms with Larry's three virtues, doesn't it? And the main point is, even if you think they are jerks, you still help them. That has to count for something.

Answer (score 4):

**It depends.**

We would have to see the actual code. What you've shown is a bit ambiguous. However, there are two scenarios.

1. **You can't**

   If your code is not exactly like what you have shown as pseudo-code, then there is no chance to do that. Consider this code in `&module1::function`.

   ```
   sub function {
       my $obj = Module2->new;
       # ... more stuff
       return;
   }
   ```

   In this case, you are not returning anything, and the `$obj` is *lexically scoped*. A [lexical scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping) means that it only exists inside of the closest `{}` block (and all blocks inside that). That's the block of the `function` sub. Once the program returns out of that sub, the variable goes *out of scope* and the object is destroyed. There is no way to get to it afterwards. It's gone.

   Even if it was not destroyed, you cannot reach into a different scope.
2. **You can**

   If you however return the object from the function, then you'd have to assign it in your script, and then you can access it later. If the code is exactly what you've shown above, this works.

   ```
   sub function {
       my $obj = Module2->new;
       # nothing here
   }
   ```

   In Perl, subs always return the last true statement. If you don't have a `return` and the last statement is the `Module2->new` call, then the result of that statement, which is the object, is returned. Of course it also works if you actually `return` explicitly.

   ```
   sub function {
       return Module2->new;
   }
   ```

   So if you assign that to a variable in your script, you can access it in the script.

   ```
   my $obj = module1->function();
   ```

   This is similar to [the factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

This is vague, but without more information it's impossible to answer the question more precicely.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, apparently I'm trying to acces a scoped out variable which is impossible since it gets lost because it holds a null reference when it gets out of the `{ }` scope.